# React - Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am using **useAxios** hook to fetch data from Api then use add data to global state by **Constate** library. 
However, I am getting error: **"Maximum update depth exceeded "**. So, how to make it work ? Also, what is best practice to handle asynchronous Api and global state in my use case ?

**In index Component:**

```
  const {loading, error} = useGetFavoriteTracks()
  const {state} = useTrackContext()
```

**In useGetFavoriteTracks.js**, fetch data then add favorite tracks to global state

```
export const useGetFavoriteTracks = params => {
  const { data, error, loading } = useAxios({
    axiosInstance: myApiAxiosInstance,
    url: myApiEndPoint.FAVORITE_TRACKS
  });

  const { addFavoriteTracks } = useTrackContext();
  addFavoriteTracks(data); //add favorite tracks to global state
  return { loading, error };
};
```

**TrackContext.js**

```
const useTrack = params => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const addFavoriteTracks = (data) => {  
    dispatch({
        type: trackActionTypes.FAVORITE_TRACKS_FETCHED_SUCCESS,
        payload: data
    })  
  }
  return {state, addFavoriteTracks}
}
export const [TrackProvider, useTrackContext] = constate(useTrack);
```

Comment: Where did you get this error? From the API or redux/react?

Comment: Hi I got this error from React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb: any direct or indirect call to `setState` or `dispatch` must not be fired in the process of rendering.

In useGetFavoriteTracks you must not unconditionally call  `addFavoriteTracks(data);` like that. Put that call inside `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!loading && data) addFavoriteTracks(data);
}, [loading, data])
```